# PHP - How to show columns with min-max values

Tags: php

I have this simple pricing table. I'd want to insert another 2 columns displaying MIN and MAX values from column *$przoff*.
Here's a screenshot that shows how columns should look like:

[image]

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $cod=mysql_result($result,$i,"cod_int");
    $name=mysql_result($result,$i,"nome");
    $conf=mysql_result($result,$i,"conf");
    $type=mysql_result($result,$i,"tipo");
    $cconf=mysql_result($result,$i,"cost");
    $cunit=mysql_result($result,$i,"costo_prod");
    $incqta=mysql_result($result,$i,"incid_qta");

    $inconf=($cconf*$incqta/100)+($cunit*$incqta/100);

    if ($cunit > 0 && $cunit <= 0.2500) {
        $incprd=$cunit*10/100; }
    elseif ($cunit > 0.2500 && $cunit <= 0.5000) {
        $incprd=$cunit*5/100; }
    else {
        $incprd=0; }

    $przoff=($cconf+$cunit+$inconf+$incprd);
?>

<tr>
/* TABLE CONTENT */
</tr>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: You need to find `min` & `max` beforehand to display like that. You can display in the bottom with ease otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the min and max value before printing the table with same process. Then print in table.

Process 1:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $cunit  = mysql_result($result, $i, "costo_prod");
    $incqta = mysql_result($result, $i, "incid_qta");

    $inconf = ($cconf * $incqta / 100) + ($cunit * $incqta / 100);

    if ($cunit > 0 && $cunit <= 0.2500) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 10 / 100;
    } elseif ($cunit > 0.2500 && $cunit <= 0.5000) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 5 / 100;
    } else {
        $incprd = 0;
    }

    $przoff = ($cconf + $cunit + $inconf + $incprd);

    if ($i == 0) {
        $min_val = $przoff;
        $max_val = $przoff;
    } else {
        if ($przoff < $min_val) {
            $min_val = $przoff;
        }
        if ($przoff > $max_val) {
            $max_val = $przoff;
        }
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    $i++;
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $cod    = mysql_result($result, $i, "cod_int");
    $name   = mysql_result($result, $i, "nome");
    $conf   = mysql_result($result, $i, "conf");
    $type   = mysql_result($result, $i, "tipo");
    $cconf  = mysql_result($result, $i, "cost");
    $cunit  = mysql_result($result, $i, "costo_prod");
    $incqta = mysql_result($result, $i, "incid_qta");

    $inconf = ($cconf * $incqta / 100) + ($cunit * $incqta / 100);

    if ($cunit > 0 && $cunit <= 0.2500) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 10 / 100;
    } elseif ($cunit > 0.2500 && $cunit <= 0.5000) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 5 / 100;
    } else {
        $incprd = 0;
    }

    $przoff  = ($cconf + $cunit + $inconf + $incprd);
    $min_val = $min_val;
    $max_val = $max_val;
    ?>

    <tr>
        /* TABLE CONTENT */
    </tr>

    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Process 2:

```
<?php
$min_val = "";
$max_val = "";

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $cunit  = mysql_result($result, $i, "costo_prod");
    $incqta = mysql_result($result, $i, "incid_qta");

    $inconf = ($cconf * $incqta / 100) + ($cunit * $incqta / 100);

    if ($cunit > 0 && $cunit <= 0.2500) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 10 / 100;
    } elseif ($cunit > 0.2500 && $cunit <= 0.5000) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 5 / 100;
    } else {
        $incprd = 0;
    }

    $przoff = ($cconf + $cunit + $inconf + $incprd);

    if ($przoff < $min_val || empty($min_val)) {
        $min_val = $przoff;
    }
    if ($przoff > $max_val || empty($max_val)) {
        $max_val = $przoff;
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    $i++;
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $cod    = mysql_result($result, $i, "cod_int");
    $name   = mysql_result($result, $i, "nome");
    $conf   = mysql_result($result, $i, "conf");
    $type   = mysql_result($result, $i, "tipo");
    $cconf  = mysql_result($result, $i, "cost");
    $cunit  = mysql_result($result, $i, "costo_prod");
    $incqta = mysql_result($result, $i, "incid_qta");

    $inconf = ($cconf * $incqta / 100) + ($cunit * $incqta / 100);

    if ($cunit > 0 && $cunit <= 0.2500) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 10 / 100;
    } elseif ($cunit > 0.2500 && $cunit <= 0.5000) {
        $incprd = $cunit * 5 / 100;
    } else {
        $incprd = 0;
    }

    $przoff  = ($cconf + $cunit + $inconf + $incprd);
    $min_val = $min_val;
    $max_val = $max_val;
    ?>

    <tr>
        /* TABLE CONTENT */
    </tr>

    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Only difference is min value and max value initializing.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. It works for $max_val, but $min_val displays 0. as you can see here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12874898/tab_minmax.JPG